# Count cells that are colored with additional criteria?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am trying to automate a process at work and I am having difficulty getting the 'Mid' column to count properly. I basically want to use a COUNTIF function as you see off to the side, but I want to filter it through the green cells then count the name. Is this possible?

I am pretty new to VBA itself, but I would say I have a solid understanding with functions.

I was able to create a function using VBA through a youtube tutorial (this is why you see 13 in the column). However, it isn't exactly what I am looking for, but it is a step in the right direction.

```
function Countif_by_Color(rl As Range, r2 As Range) As Long

Application.Volatile

Dim x As Long
Dim cel As Range

x = 0

For Each cel In rl
    If cel.Interior.Color = r2.Interior.Color Then
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next

Countif_by_Color = x

End Function
```

Comment: You have to add the additional criteria into the `For Each` loop. By the way, this function will not recalculate automatically when you change a cell color.

Comment: Side note: if the color is applied by conditional formatting, then this won't work. Instead, replicate the logic of the conditional formatting rule.

Comment: Are you missing a screenshot?

Comment: FYI a bit faster if you first read `r2.Interior.Color` into a `Long` variable and then compare against that.  No need to read it each time through the loop.